# .NET MVC 4 - Button actions in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've currently got a View like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Compare", "Carousel", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
@foreach (var product in Model.Products)
{
        <tr>
             <td>@product.Provider.Name</td>
             <td>&pound;@Math.Round(product.MonthlyPremium, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)</td>
             <td>@Html.ActionLink("More Details", "MoreDetails", new { id = product.ProductId })</td>
             <td><button name="compare" value="@product.ProductId">Compare</button</td>
        </tr>
}
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Compare(ProductsWithDetailModel model) // This is a guess, Model may not persist? 
 {
       // Code here

       return View("Index", model);
 }
```

What I actually want is, when a button is clicked, the Controller is going to be called and the product that has been selected (the button clicked) will be added to a list of items.

How do I actually find out which button has been clicked in the Controller? How come I cant find *any* tutorials out there on the web that have done this before, surely its basic functionality? Or am I approaching it wrong?

Comment: Could you give more details about use case? Is it submit form on button click or what?

Comment: Can you please put ProductsWithDetailModel code also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC takes all inputs and send it by a verb to an action. The bind of these controls is made by the `name` attribute on your View and the value is made by depending of what control we are talking about (text, checkbox, radio, select, button etc...). You could have a a property on your `ProductsWithDetailModel` called *compare* and it would recevie the value of the button you've clicked.

Comment: That worked, I set the name of the button and, hey presto, it all worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How about having 1 form per item?

E.g.

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Products)
{
    <tr>
         <td>@product.Provider.Name</td>
         <td>&pound;@Math.Round(product.MonthlyPremium, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)</td>
         <td>@Html.ActionLink("More Details", "MoreDetails", new { id = product.ProductId })</td>
         <td>
             @using (Html.BeginForm("Compare", "Carousel", FormMethod.Post)) 
             {
                 <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="@product.ProductId"  />
                 <button name="compare">Compare</button>
             }
         </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: I used the below answer and it all worked fine, the ProductsWithDetail model got updated with the "name" property of the button, which is great. But thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

use onclick. set js hidden value in loop. in controller check.